# How to send email by gmail in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

> MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
>   MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
>   MAIL_PORT=587
>   MAIL_USERNAME=semhnh@gmail.com
>   MAIL_PASSWORD=********
>   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
>   MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=semhnh@gmail.com
>   MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

MY ERROR--> 
Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required

how to send gmail email in larave, im very tired in this error, please help me

this is my .env file
[my env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPGlc.jpg)

this is may error image
[email error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXhQj.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post images - edit your question and add your code and errors as text.

Comment: Ok sir, i edit and add my quection code in text, can you help me please

Comment: have you tried `MAIL_PORT=465` ?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail SMTP Settings

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ENTER_YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS(GMAIL)
MAIL_PASSWORD=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

You must configure your Google Account

> Login to your Google Email Account and click on Google Account Button.
>   This button is display when you click on the profile picture in your
>   Gmail Dashboard as shown.
>
> Once you are on My Account Page then click on Security and scroll down
>   to the bottom and you will find ‘Less secure app access’ settings.
>   Click on the radio button to set it ON.

[image]

Complete reading [here](https://medium.com/@agavitalis/how-to-send-an-email-in-laravel-using-gmail-smtp-server-53d962f01a0c)

Comment: dear sir, i already done this, but didn;t work sir, help me please   https://imgur.com/U3uGrWW

Comment: are you using it for your localhost testing purpose ?

Comment: yes sir, im using localhost, email service is working or not working in localhost ???

Comment: You may swich to mailtrap, it's quite easy to use than gmail