# Sending email work fine in laravel with mailtrap, but not working in gmail, outlook, etc

Tags: laravel, email

I'm trying to send email using laravel. Its going well when testing with mailtrap. But I tried with gmail, outlook, namecheap's email, page do not stop loading and time out. There is no response code.

Here is my gmail's smtp setting
( I' using app password for google account. not account password )

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=*************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

My namecheap's smtp

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.privateemail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@myemail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mail@myemail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

But when I use mailtrap, its ok.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=*********
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I also tried with outlook mail. but not working

Comment: So... 2 links to start reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59974019/1294911 and https://medium.com/@agavitalis/how-to-send-an-email-in-laravel-using-gmail-smtp-server-53d962f01a0c hope it helps

Comment: i already tried that but not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this post is for email verification, but you can try to adjust the smtp setting [https://codelapan.com/post/how-to-create-email-verification-in-laravel-8-with-gmail](https://codelapan.com/post/how-to-create-email-verification-in-laravel-8-with-gmail)